# Matieral Design Shape Theming with Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, material-design, androidx

I'm trying to follow [this](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/shape) documentation on shape theming and I'm hitting a wall.

here is my styles.xml file:

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/very_light_gray</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/light_gray</item>
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/button_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/gray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary</item>

        <item name="shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.SmallComponent</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceMediumComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.MediumComponent</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceLargeComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.LargeComponent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShapeAppearance.SmallComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
        <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">4dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShapeAppearance.MediumComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.MediumComponent">
        <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShapeAppearance.LargeComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.LargeComponent">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">4dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

When I go and build my app I get a list of errors:

[image: figure-1]

Here's the packages I have installed:

[image: figure-2]

I'm not sure if I'm missing a package or if Xamarin.Android has yet to support this. I know there are other ways to do this but I'd prefer to do it this way if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material` nuget to the latest version,and install `Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.UI` nuget,it works for me.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Comment: looks like I needed to get the 1.1.0 pre-release of the material package to get it to work in case someone sees this before that version is out of beta.